# YouTube API PlaylistItems/list limited to 5000 results?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of all titles from YouTube channel `machinima`. Machinima currently has (I'm guessing here) tens of thousands of videos.

The following Python script is supposed to walk the chain of pages containing playlist items (the playlist being user's uploads).

```
channels_response = youtube.channels().list(
    id=DEFAULT_CHANNEL,
    part="contentDetails"
).execute()

if len(channels_response["items"]) == 0:
    channels_response = youtube.channels().list(
        forUsername=DEFAULT_CHANNEL,
        part="contentDetails"
    ).execute()


for channel in channels_response["items"]:
    # From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
    # of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
    uploads_list_id = channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

    print "Videos in list %s" % uploads_list_id

    # Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
    playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        playlistId=uploads_list_id,
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=50
    )

    while playlistitems_list_request:
        playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()

        # Print information about each video.
        for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
            title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
            video_id = playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]
            print video_id
            videos.append(video_id)
            titles.append(title)

        playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response)
```

However, for some reason, I always end up getting no more than `5,000 videos`.

I checked the API documentation, but there is no reference of limit of such sort. The code I'm using is from the official documentation too (slightly modified) and should work.

Does anyone know how could I get ALL the videos from Machinima?

**EDIT: Update on October 20th. The limit seems to have disappeared.**

Comment: I think it's an implicit limit. Maybe you could try [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) instead and specify Machinima's `channelId` and set `type=video`.

Comment: @not_a_bot `search.list` is hard limited to 500 results.